# Why does my Ubuntu web server have so many SSL certificates in /etc/ssl/certs?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, server, certificate

I'm installing a new SSL cert for my website, and in /etc/ssl/certs I see 524 files, 3 *.crt files and a bunch of *.pem files.

My question is why are there so many files here? Should I be worried about a security breach, or is this normal?

Answer (score 4):

Those are what are known as CA Certs (Certificate Authority Certificates). They are known and trusted certificate authorities used by your system to authenticate connections to important servers such as the Ubuntu update system.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html